# Question about primes of polynomial type.

Tags: prime-numbers, symmetric-polynomials

It is well known that $50$ % of the primes are of the form $x^2 + y^2$.

Many variants exists where a rational amount of primes is of some integer polynomial form.

But I wonder ; are there integer symmetric polynomials $P$ such that $Q$  % of the primes are of the form $P$ where $Q$ is an irrational number ?

If so , does $Q$ need to be an algebraic number ?

Comment: I can not imagine a reason why Q could be transcendental ...